# serialize fieldset content of a form

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, fieldset

this is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/Pt6LQ/25/

I would to serialize only the fieldset name= cap1.

So I tried to modify

```
$('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
```

in

```
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('fieldset#cap1').serializeObject()));
```

but it doesn't work and return me {}.
How can I modify the code for serialize only one fieldset content and not all the form?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
 $('fieldset#cap1 input').serializeObject()));
```

updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pt6LQ/26/

Answer (score 0):

as you use #cap1, it should be id instead of name